# Why is useradd -p option not recommended?

Tags: password, users, docker, useradd

I've read that it is good practice with regards to security to run docker containers as non-root user, so I create a user in my Dockerfile and switch to that user in the end of the Dockerfile:

```
// Dockerfile code..

RUN useradd -m some_user

USER some_user
```

The thing is, that I want to assign this user a password, but I read in the `useradd` man page:

> -p, --password PASSWORD
> The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.
> Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.

I didn't quite get why is it not recommended. What does it mean by "Will be visible by users listing the processes"?
Plus, if all that'll be visible is the encrypted password, why should I care?

Answer (score 1):

> Will be visible by users listing the processes?

When someone on another terminal can do a

```
ps -ef
```

it will show the password.

> Plus, if all that'll be visible is the encrypted password, why should I care?

Simple: we do not compromise when it concerns basic security.

On a single user system the problem is minute. Or even less. But it is good practice: Linux is a multi user system. What you do on your own system is not good when you do it on a system with more users... it is just plain bad.

> why should I care

That is asking for opinions. You decided on that. As mentioned in the text: it is not -recommended-. Even the person that wrote that line does not care if you do use it. Otherwise you would not be able to use `-p` as an option. The same with mysql: it is not recommended to use `-p{password}` and those maintainers have actually been removing that option. Same will happen here: a couple of releases you get this as a warning and at some moment in time the option is actually disabled and then removed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Under what field in the output of ps -ef will the password be visible? And - What is a recommended way to assign a password to a newly created user?

Comment: It will be shown as part of the command.ps under CMD. 
"What is a recommended way to assign a password to a newly created user?" The versions where the system shows `password:` and you type it in.